# StatusBar presentation triggers layout cycle

Tags: ios

I am trying to reload my `UICollectionView` when a status bar has presented. I am using the Apple Delegate method for the In-Call Status bar called `(void) application:(UIApplication *)application didChangeStatusBarFrame:(CGRect)newStatusBarFrame`. Since UI events are dispatched to the main thread, in my handler for this event I tell my VC that its needs a layout update in `setNeedsLayout` and then explicitly reload my collection view cells in a batch update called from `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. I want to be certain 100% that a layout cycle will always occur each time the status bar is presented. I cannot find in the documentation whether or not this is the case.

According to Apple: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621437-viewwilllayoutsubviews a layout cycle will always be invoked when a views bounds changed. In my example my views are all constrained to the parent rootViewController's top and bottom. Thus theoretically the bound should change if they are responding the UIWindow change with the statusBar being presented.

Comment: im not sure why you want reload the collectionview when a view bounds changes,but as is understand you want to reload it when status bar appears or disappears,so why you don't simply call reladData in the didChangeStatusBarFrame callback? im think that it's really difficult to: (1) know what causes the viewwilllayoutsubviews callback to be fired, may be not the status bar,(2)you are listening to ->did<-ChangeStatusBarFrame and reload in view->willl<-ayoutsubviews you will never be sure about the order of these events, you never knows when the "will" will be fired (after the did or befor) ..

Comment: Hi @RedMak yes those are legit concerns and definitely reloadData would solve it. The goal is to avoid the unnecessary parts of reloadData (the data part of it, since we are only reloading the size of the cells, not the `cellForItemAtIndexPath`). current solution is posted below. feel free to offer your thoughts

Answer (score 0):

in the `AppDelegate` we listen for the status bar change with

```
- (void) application:(UIApplication *)application didChangeStatusBarFrame:(CGRect)newStatusBarFrame { 
    // create notification to let
    // user know app has presented status bar
    // send event in a dispatch_after so the has enough time to go through
    // a layout cycle 
 }
```

in the `TargetViewController` listen for the custom notification sent from the delegate and do the following

```
[[self.view collectionView] invalidateLayout];
[self.view setNeedsLayout];
self.customFlagToCheckInDidLayoutSubviews = YES;
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```

finally in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

```
if (self.customFlagToCheckInDidLayoutSubviews) {
     [self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
    [self.collectionView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0]];
} completion:nil];
}
```